# Why do most of the people use routes with user id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I was thinking about one thing. Because of what issued there are so many people who use user 'id' to maintaing operations on, like edit?

Example:
I go to www.example.com/user/TestUser/edit to edit my user.

Isn't that better to make routes something similar to this?:
www.example.com/user/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe look at [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) to understand why URLs are constructed this way. In short: The URL `http://www.example.com/user/marc` is thought to represent the user himself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an exact answer, however my idea is that www.example.com/user/edit should be normally used for administration pages to edit some user profile. Maybe that's the reason why it's not used in the way you explained.